# Restore partitions table

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, startup, efi

Just tried to install Windows on an external SSD, but mistakenly deleted partitions on a Mac SSD from the Windows installer. I had  2 partitions:

- Macintosh HD (APFS)
- MacData (ExFat, ~108 GB)

So I deleted system partitions (EFI, Recovery, ...) and Macintosh HD, but MacData is not touched. Just booted to recovery mode with internet connection. Disk Utility shows only MacData partition. Is there any way to recover these partitions from the Mac Recovery mode terminal?

Here is the result of `gpt -r show disk0`:

[image: Photo of Terminal output of the command 'gpt -r show disk0']

Comment: Post the output after entering the following commands. `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII"`,`diskutil unmountdisk disk0` and `dd if=/dev/disk0  bs=256 count=1 skip=1228896 | vis -cw; echo` These commands will show if the header for the APFS partition has been overwritten.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thank you for answering, just solved the problem by myself, posted solution in answers section

Answer (score 0):

- Disclaimer0: Following steps may not be valid for other macs or other versions of MacOS, i'm using Macbook Pro 16" 2019, MacOS Ventura 13.1
- Disclaimer1: Maybe this is not the best solution, just my experience of solving the problem.

So, answering to myself.

After a few hours of messing with `gpt` command, these steps helped me out:

0. Dont forget to execute `gpt -r show disk0` and remember printed result
1. `diskutil unmountDisk disk0` - unmount disk to modify GPT
2. `gpt destroy disk0` - delete old GPT
3. `gpt create disk0` - create new GPT
4. `gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0` - add record for EFI (**but the "start" and "size" is wrong at this moment**)
5. **diskutil unmountDisk disk0** - After EFI added, the partition mounts, so unmount disk to modify GPT
6. `gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 95361496 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0` - add APFS (**but the "start" and the "size" is wrong at this moment**).

   **95361496 = 95771136 (ExFAT start) - 409640 (EFI end)**

So, at this moment i have 2 records - EFI and APFS. I returned back to Disk Util and saw APFS partition shows as "disk0s2", and can not be mounted. First Aid detects problem with EFI, so we need to fix it.

I returned to Terminal, and executed `diskutil repairDisk disk0`. It asked me to allow rewrite of EFI partiton.

I executed `gpt -r show disk0` and i saw something strange: size of EFI partiton was decreased to 76800, "start" changed to **6**, and free space appeared between EFI (1) and APFS (2).

I deleted APFS record:

```
diskutil unmountDisk disk0
gpt remove -i 2 disk0
```

And recreated with new start point and size:

```
gpt add -i 2 -b 76806 -s 95694330 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
```

**95694330 = 95771136 (ExFAT start) - 76806 (EFI end)**

And voila: `diskutil list` shows all of my APFS containers (Macintosh HD and others)

At the end, add ExFAT record:

```
gpt add -i 3 -b 95771136 -s 26366976 -t EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 disk0
```

Now i can boot to MacOS :)

Note: Luckily ExFAT record wasn't deleted at the beginning, so this is the key to the whole solution, overwise i don't know how to determine where APFS partition "ends" and where ExFAT partition "starts"

Record types:

```
ExFAT - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
APFS - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC 
EFI - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
```

`gpt` command flags:

```
-i - record index
-b - "start" of partition
-s - "size" of partition
-t - type of record
```

So, simplified *posible* solution **(ONLY IF YOU HAVE APFS ONLY OR APFS AND EXFAT, BUT EXFAT RECORD NOT DELETED)**:

`gpt -r show disk0` - **TAKE A PHOTO OF PRINTED RESULT**

```
diskutil unmountDisk disk0
gpt destroy disk0
gpt create disk0
gpt add -i 1 -b 6 -s 76800 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0
diskutil unmountDisk disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 76806 -s **APFS_SIZE (SEE BELOW)** -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0

// IF YOU HAD EXFAT PARTITION, SKIP IF NOT
diskutil unmountDisk disk0
gpt add -i 3 -b *EXFAT_PARTITION_START* -s *EXFAT_PARTITION_SIZE* -t EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 disk0
```

About APFS_SIZE:

- If you had ExFAT partition after APFS partition:

  `APFS_SIZE = EXFAT_PARTITION_START - 76806`
- If you had APFS partition only :

  - `APFS_SIZE = "Sec GPT table" start - 76806`
  - OR (try different)
  - `APFS_SIZE = "Sec GPT table" start - 76806 - 16`

Comment: I believe when the APFS partition is equal to or larger than the APFS container, then the APFS volumes within will mount. Still, I think it to be wise to verify both are the same size and adjust the partition size if not.

Comment: @DavidAnderson good advise, thank you. i'll check it later